# Rvalue references, copy and move

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Consider following section of code for swap :

```
//for some type T
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

and this one below :

```
//for some type T
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp = static_cast<T&&>(a);
    a = static_cast<T&&>(b);
    b = static_cast<T&&>(temp);
}
```

I have following doubts :
What is the difference between them? I mean why the first swap is more expensive than the second one ?

Reference : The c++ programming language 7.7.2

Comment: The first one does three copies, the second one does theee moves. In general moves can be implemented more efficiently than copies, but obviously it does depend on the type of object being moved or copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between them? I mean why the first swap is more expensive than the second one ?

The second one enable move for types that support it (ie having move assignment operator). Those types include standard vector, string, etc.

For basic types (int, bool, etc.) that does not support move semantic, there is no difference, it's a normal copy.

Comment: Is that fully true? The compiler could do any optimization that does not have side effects. So a `Tp a, b;  std::swap(a,b); a.foo(b)` could be optimized to `Tp a, b; b.foo(a)` for the second one. I know this is a very artificial code construct, but I could imagine, that there are real use cases.